# Flatten data in one column and then copy rest of row cells to the new flattened column

Tags: google-sheets

I have certain type of data :

[Data Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0nUS.png)

Now I would need to flatten the middle column to make each "size" into its own row but still copy the "info" corresponding to the correct "size" row, as displayed here :

[Data Output that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6OpI.png)

I don't really know how to "copy" the information in the row to the new flattened rows, any ideas?

Comment: Any help on this one? I dont even think if anything like this is possible

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IF(B1:D="",,A1:A&"♦"&B1:D&"♦"&E1:E)),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"))
```

[image]